# How create a button which can a safe as website

Tags: javascript

I have problem with button which should show windows save as when click them.
When i click this button I want that show me this window:
[Save as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHiRl.png)

Comment: this may be a starting point - https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Shouldn't "safe" be "save"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the (short! friendly!) introductory [tour] some time. What problem do you have? Please [edit] your question and add this, as well as your current code. See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

You try this if you want user to save just a part of `text/code` from your site

```html
<a href="data:application/text;charset=utf-8, Hello World" download="filename.php">Save</a>
```

Clicking on this will save a file called `filname.php` which will contain string `Hello World`

There are many library's that can enable that functionality you want. Just google it